# Resource images really dim when painted in android app

Tags: android, image, brightness

I'm trying to load in two images (both 800 x 1280) to use as a perpetually scrolling background in my game. I can load them in fine using the following code:

```
public Image newImage(String imageName, ImageFormat format) {
    Config config = null;
    if (format == ImageFormat.RGB565)
        config = Config.RGB_565;
    else if (format == ImageFormat.ARGB4444)
        config = Config.ARGB_4444;
    else
        config = Config.ARGB_8888;

    Options options = new Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = config;

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        int id = resources.getIdentifier("<package>"+imageName, null, null);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, id, options);
        if (bitmap == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't load bitmap from resources");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to load image");
    } 

    if (bitmap.getConfig() == Config.RGB_565)
        format = ImageFormat.RGB565;
    else if (bitmap.getConfig() == Config.ARGB_4444)
        format = ImageFormat.ARGB4444;
    else
        format = ImageFormat.ARGB8888;

    return new AndroidImage(bitmap, format);
}
```

But when I paint them on the screen they are significantly dimmer than the actual images. I've made sure the screen brightness was adjusted to 100% and I've tried all 3 different image formats. Here is an example of what's happening:

actual image

> [image]

screenshot

> [image]

Comment: Probably it is not due to the image but to the way you display it. Is there some alpha set on the view?

Comment: I don't believe so, I can post the code if you'd like though.

Comment: This question is old, but I'm having a similar problem loading an image from a file and displaying it - it shows up very dim, but only on certain phones. I imagine @Henry is right that it has something to do with alpha on the view, but I don't know where that's getting set or why it only affects certain phones.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what was affecting you, but I had a similar problem and below is the solution I found.

I have a splash screen activity, which uses an ImageView, and dynamically loads an image from a file to put into it. Here's an excerpt from the activity's onCreate():

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

File splashImageFile = new File(dir, filename);
Drawable splashDrawable = Drawable.createFromPath(splashImageFile.getAbsolutePath());
if (splashDrawable != null) {
    imageView.setImageDrawable(splashDrawable);
}
// The following works but maybe only for newer versions of the API:
// imageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(splashImageFile));
```

This would work fine on most phones, but on a couple of them, the image would show up about 50% dim.

Here was the fix that worked for me. I added the following after populating `imageView` (and before loading the image from the file):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
    float alpha = imageView.getAlpha();
    Log.d(TAG, "alpha is " + alpha);
    if (alpha < 1.0)
        imageView.setAlpha(1.0f);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        int imageAlpha = imageView.getImageAlpha();
        Log.d(TAG, "imageAlpha is " + imageAlpha);
        if (imageAlpha < 255)
            imageView.setImageAlpha(255);
    }
}
```

On the phones where the problem occurred, the above logging would show that imageAlpha was 55, instead of 255. I don't know how that happened. But setting it to 255 fixed the problem.

I first tried setting `android:imageAlpha="255"` in the layout xml file for the activity, but got an error saying that there was no such attribute. Thankfully, `setImageAlpha()` at runtime did the trick.